# Handling subscription canceling in my app from Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, firebase-notifications, android-billing, play-billing-library

Currently I use a separate backend to acknowledge purchases (Subscriptions & One-time products) made from Google Play.

But when a user cancels a subscription from Google Play app, and leaves my app in background, there is no way for me to know that user is no longer subscribed so that I can refresh app content for example.

So is there a way that Google Play notifies me when the subscriptions get canceled?

Note: Backend already sends a notification (Firebase notification) to my app when this cancellation happens; but when the app is in the background and the user opens the app again normally (not by clicking on the notification banner) I can't catch this notification.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for you to always capture not subscription accounts is by putting a validation around your application which will make sure that those accounts have subscription.

Create a small function to verify, and call this function where ever you think they might trick your application by keeping it in the background while canceling their subscription.